# Loop through JSON object to get value for given property name

Tags: json, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I have some JSON-objects and I need to fetch property values for them.
My situation is based on this query:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
v_whatever character varying := 'a';
v_res character varying;
BEGIN
SELECT params->>v_whatever FROM user_info1 WHERE uid = 9 INTO v_res;
RAISE NOTICE 'v_res: %', v_res ;
END; $$
```

In table, value for column params(type json) is: `{"a":"b","b":"c","c":"d"}` ,
Query returns `v_res: b`

Because I don't have specific property names, code looks like this:

```
DECLARE
v_temp char varying;
v_obj char varying[];
comp char varying[];
BEGIN
SELECT json_object_keys(params) FROM  user_info1 WHERE uid = p_uid into v_temp;
SELECT params->>v_temp FROM user_info1 WHERE uid = 9 INTO v_obj;
```

Comment: Is this a node.js (javascript) question or a postgresql? ....

Comment: sorry my bad, it's postgresql but json object relys on node ...

Answer (score 0):

A basic plpgsql [`FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
   v_whatever text := 'a';
   v_res text;
BEGIN

FOR v_res IN
   SELECT params->>v_whatever
   FROM   user_info1
   WHERE  uid = 9
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE 'v_res: %', v_res;
END LOOP;

END;
$$
```

Note that a set-based approach is often more efficient than looping. Look to [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) ..

Comment: What does `NED LOOP` mean? :D

Comment: @Daria: Was short for *Nonsense Espied by Daria*. :)